# ngx datatable pagination with angular2

Tags: css, angular, datatable, pagination

I'm working with angular 2 and ngx-datatable, and I'd like to know if it's possible to display the pagination on the top of the table instead of the bottom using th html features, or CSS trick?

the html code:

```
<ngx-datatable class="material"
[rows]="rows"
[columnMode]="'force'"
[headerHeight]="40"
[footerHeight]="40"
[rowHeight]="30"
[externalPaging]="true"
[limit]="50"
[selectionType]="'checkbox'">
<ngx-datatable-column
        [width]="30"
        [sortable]="false"
        [canAutoResize]="false"
        [draggable]="false"
        [resizeable]="false"
        [headerCheckboxable]="true"
        [checkboxable]="true">
      </ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="Name">
            <ng-template let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                <div class="redNumber">{{value}}</div>
            </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="Title"></ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="company"></ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="Status" [cellClass]="getStatusClass"></ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="Last connexion"></ngx-datatable-column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS solution is the folowing:

```
.ngx-datatable {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
.datatable-pager {
    position: absolute;
    top: -56px;
    right: 0;
}
```

This is not the solution I wanted first, but unable to find another way, hope that helps.